# How to access two arrays in one loop in awk

Tags: arrays, for-loop, awk

In this code:

```
for (i in a) {
    print i, a[i]
}
```

Can I use another array? Like this code:

```
for (i in a) {
    print i, a[i]
    print i, b[i]    
}
```

If not, how can I access two or more arrays in one loop?

Comment: yes you can use that code

Comment: It may be better to show us what you like to do.  We may be able to help you with the code.  And yes, this is valid code.

Comment: There's nothing special about `i` that ties it to `a` when used in the for loop. It gets a value that if it happens to also be an index in another array it will work fine.

Comment: You can use that code, as long as the keys in `a` and `b` are the same. Otherwise, you will only be able to access the elements of `a`. At the moment, this question is too general to be answered as it depends entirely on what exactly you are trying to do. Can you edit your question to make it more specific?